# How do I connect a photodiode?

Tags: photodiode

I'm trying to design a circuit to measure the ambient visible light (380nm to 750nm). Accuracy isn't too important.

I've been looking at photodiodes, but I'm not sure how to connect them up.

I need the following requirements from my circuit:

- low power
- low accuracy
- low cost photodiode (e.g. [this on digikey](http://www.digikey.ie/product-detail/en/SFH3410/475-1083-2-ND/607293))
- AD convert signal for uC

I was thinking of some sort of voltage divider with a photodiode in the circuit? Then connecting this to an op amp, before going to the AD pin of a uC.

Comment: Keep in mind that the SFH3410 has been [discontinued](http://catalog.osram-os.com/catalogue/catalogue.do;jsessionid=8D480128A4E2FC4C86FC3C0AE21ACDCB?act=downloadFile&favOid=02000002000307ab000100b6) since March 2005. May be hard to get. Digikey doesn't list a price either. You can probably only buy the whole stock.

Comment: @stevenvh the replacement is simply a RoHS-compliant equivalent of the same item. Same code but with "-Z" appended.

Answer (score 22):

Photodiodes are easy. You connect them **reversed** to the +5V (cathode!) and the anode to a resistor to ground.

[image]

If light falls on the diode it will cause a current through the resistor, which will cause a voltage across it. So you can choose the sensitivity by choosing a value for the resistor. You'll have to make sure that there remains enough voltage drop across the photodiode.

[image]

Note that the SFH3410 is a **phototransistor**, you use them in the same way, collector to +5V, emitter to resistor. They have a much larger current, in fact they contain a photodiode, whose current is amplified by a transistor. (Nice product, that SFH3410. I've also used it.)

[image]

This is the most important graph from the datasheet. It shows current as function of luminosity. Note that both scales are exponential. 10 lux is twilight, 1000 lux is a brightly lit desktop for precision work. Direct sunlight can reach 100 000 lux. So if you want to measure inside lighting you could use a 12k\$\Omega\$ resistor, which will give you 3.6V at 1000 lux. The SFH3410 will work well up to 4.5V output at a 5V power supply.

Comment: Since accuracy is not needed, trans-conductance amplifiers are not needed, right?

Comment: @abdullah - with opamp? You'll typically connect the photodiode to V-, and I don't know if he has that.

Comment: Yes, I've meant op-amps, and trans-impedance :) I shouldn't talk about subjects that I even don't even know their name.

Comment: @abdullah - you got the "trans" right! ;-) The name comes from the transfer function, output/input. That's a voltage output divided by a current input. So V/I = impedance. I/V (like in MOSFETs) would be transconductance.

Comment: Hey, many thanks for your very useful reply. I would like to use an op-amp if possible?

Comment: @Eamorr - Sure, what supply voltages do you have? Positive and negative. BTW, why do you want the opamp? You only need a resistor.