# Understanding basic photoresistor circuit

Tags: photodiode, photoresistor

I'm new to electronics, so I just can't wrap my head around how this photoresistor circuit works.

I understand the following:

1. the photodiode can be understood as a variable resistor (i.e. works in principle the same as a photoresistor)
2. I want to measure the difference in voltage, that is caused by that variable resistor

Intuitively, I'd like to take a voltage measurement before (source: 5V) and after the diode. Can someone explain, maybe using an intuitive analogy (e.g. water current?), **why this only works with an additional resistor** (like below, copied from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33659/how-do-i-connect-a-photodiode))?

I built a working sensor using the arduino starter kit photoresistor ([datasheet](https://www.arduino.cc/documents/datasheets/HW5P-1.pdf)) using a 10kOhm resistor and a 5V source but want to understand it better.

**Edit: afer helpful comments, this question is basically:
 
a) what is the difference between a photodiode and -resistor 
 
b) why does a voltage divider need 2 resistors**

[image]

Comment: the second question (edit) is still not entirely clear to me in all honesty, I can't find an intuitive example that does not go along the lines of 'it's because Ohms law'

Answer (score 10):

The HW5P-1 is in fact a phototransistor.

This is the diagram of the example circuit from the datasheet:

[image]

The circuit symbol is clearly a phototransistor, regardless of what the poorly translated text says.

A phototransistor and a photoresistor (like a cadmium sulfide cell) both react to light, but they are fundamentally different in how they operate.

A [photoresistor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor) is a resistor whose resistance changes in response to light.

A [phototransistor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode#Other_modes_of_operation) actually generates current from light in its base to emitter junction, which allows current to flow through the collector to the emitter.  It is in effect a tiny solar cell connected to a single transistor amplifier.

You can use both to detect light, but you should familiarize yourself with how they work.

A short list of differences:

1. Photoresistors are slow.  You can't really receive a modulated light signal with them.  Phototransistors are **much** faster, and can pickup light signals modulated with signals that can reach megahertz frequencies.
2. Photoresistors keep changing resistance even after the light is gone.  Datasheets specify the "dark resistance" for a time period in absolute darkness for this reason.
3. Photoresistors are usually most sensitive to visible light.  Phototransistors are usually most sensitive to infrared.  Results can be very different from what you expect if you just replace a photoresistor with a phototransistor without considering that difference.
4. They have different response curves.  If you use the same circuit with both, they will react differently to the same light intensity.  This might change your threshholds if you are using a simple level detector.

So, really, they aren't the same so don't use the terms interchangeably.

They can carry out similar tasks, but you have to use each as intended. Using one just like the other will lead to bad results.

Answer (score 5):

The datasheet of this device isn't terribly clear. At some points it claims to be a drop-in replacement for a CdS sensor (i.e. a resistor whose resistance varies with light intensity) and at other points it seems to be a photodiode (i.e. a semiconductor device that creates a small current when illuminated with light). Some of the details in the datasheet suggest that it is a photodiode (and not a photoresistor) but I'll include both devices in my answer.

### Photodiode (photoconductive mode)

If this device is actually a photodiode, you can use a very similar circuit, but the principle of operation (and some of the math) is different.

The photodiode acts similarly to a normal diode when reverse biased, meaning that it blocks most current and a little bit of current "leaks". By Ohm's law, the output voltage is equal to the leaking current times the resistor (labeled R in the schematic in your question). This means that there is a small output voltage even if the device is kept in complete darkness.

Due to device physics, when light hits the device, it allows more current to pass<sup>1</sup>. The extra current causes the output voltage to rise, again due to Ohm's law.

A phototransistor acts similarly on the outside when properly biased (i.e. it allows a bit of leakage current and then much more when illuminated) but the working principle involves some different device physics.

### Photodiode (photovoltaic mode)

The photodiode can also be operated like a tiny solar panel--it is not reverse biased with a voltage. This prevents leakage current from introducing background noise, but also makes the current smaller and harder to detect. A special circuit that makes use of an amplifier chip is needed to make such a setup work.

For reasons not discussed here, this circuit is also slower. You probably won't use it unless you have a specialty application that requires it. Additionally, the sensor you have might be unsuitable for this mode, since the manufacturer site [mentions](http://www.szhaiwang.cn/Product/detail/l/cn/id/82.html) "Built-in micro-signal CMOS amplifier" **possibly** built into the device. The datasheet does not mention this, curiously.

<sup>1</sup> When the diode is reverse biased, a region known as a depletion region is formed. This region contains few electrons and few holes meaning that current has a hard time flowing. Light can create new pairs of electrons and holes, which create current right away.

### CdS cell / photoresistor

If we consider this device as a drop-in replacement for a CdS (cadmium sulfide) photoresistor with the circuit you show, we end up with a voltage divider. I'm going to present this first because it's simplest, and a fair assumption for some cases.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2floLMx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's assume that the output is hooked up to an Arduino analog pin, meaning that it draws little to no current. Then, the current from the battery is given by \$\frac{5\,\text{V}}{R_1+R_2}\$ because the resistors are in series. By Ohm's law, the output voltage is:

$$ 5\,\text{V} + \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}$$

As you can see, this voltage depends on the value of R1, which varies with light.

Comment: Thank you this made things a bit clearer. Questions: isn't the current ouput from the battery constant / defined by the battery? Why can't we leave out R2?

Comment: @user2305193 The *voltage* from the battery is constant. The current from the battery arises because of the voltage-current relationship for the circuit connected to the battery. We need R2 because we need a voltage divider to take a measurement with an Arduino, because it measures voltage and not current.

Comment: A quick review of [Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) should clear this up for you.

Comment: I see, so what you're saying is the current output of the battery depends on the resistors we put in the circuit. That makes sense with Ohms law. I'm unclear on voltage dividers, but I'll read up, I didn't understand it's the same principle

Comment: @user2305193 A voltage divider is the result of applying Ohm's law twice: You know the voltage of the battery and the total resistance, and you get the current. You then know the current and the bottom resistor and you then get the voltage at the point between the two resistors. (I assume that whatever you have hooked up to the voltage divider doesn't consume any current). For photodiode, it's a bit different: When properly powered the photodiode gives a known current for a known illumination. That current goes through the resistor so Ohm's law gives you the voltage across it.

Comment: I'm getting there, I was suffering from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). My real questions was, why does a voltage divider need two resistors. Thank you for helping me understand. If I got it correctly, if the current were constant, only one resistor would be needed - but this is not usually the case.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear from the datasheet exactly what kind of device you have. I've answered based on the assumption that this is a photodiode or phototransistor.

First, a photodiode (or phototransistor) will act more like a light-controlled current source than like a variable resistor.

Second, consider what happens if you measure the voltage across R rather than across the photodiode.

Comment: with the measurement as in diagram, don't we compare ground to whatever the photodiode outputs? I just don't get it

Comment: It could be a light dependent resistor like a cadmium sulfide cell, in which case calling it a diode is the error, not the part where the OP says it's a variable resistor.  Impossible to know without a link to the datasheet.  (Hint to the OP.)  It's not hugely relevant to the OP's basic question, but details can be important.

Comment: attached datasheet arduino homepage - oddly, on the package it says photoresistor, on the datasheet it says phototransistor

Comment: @user2305193 According to the front page of the datasheet, it is a "Replacement of CdS", so it's intended to be used as a variable, light-sensitive resistor. The data tables themselves make it seem like a photodiode (i.e. light-induced photocurrent).

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov thanks, this is all profoundly puzzling and confusing to me

Comment: @user2305193 I'll write up an answer shortly.

Comment: @user2305193 I've added an answer that might describe the device's operation a bit better.

Comment: @JohnD, at one point they even call it a "photosensitive tube". Looks like the datasheet was generated by machine translation from Chinese.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov, despite the front-page claim, they never specify a resistance in dark conditions or a change in resistance with applied light. So I think it's more likely the device is a photodiode or phototransistor than a variable-resistance device. Such a device might still be substituted for a CdS cell in certain circuits, over certain ranges of input light, so the front-page claim isn't necessarily invalid.

Comment: @ThePhoton Understood; that grew on me as I was writing my answer and was reviewing the datasheet (for some reason or another my experience with photodiodes has always been in photovoltaic mode). I'll leave the photoresistor model in for completeness (and in case the OP or other readers do end up using a photoresistor at a later point)

Comment: uhm. I realized my question is about photoresistors, I'm sorry for the confusion. Please leave everything in, as it's actually really helpful

Comment: Now that you understand, ask yourself, does the phototransistor current charge or discharge the battery in this mode?

Comment: discharge_________